# How to access the request object in FormView

Tags: python, django

I want to access the request object in FormView and get client IP. As we all know, it's not very reliable to put a hidden-field in the html form because it can be changed by user if user wants do so. Therefore, I choose to do it in the backed. I use ModelForm as the `form_class` of FormView and exclude the `ip` field in the form. Here come the problem, I do know how to add the `ip` field dynamically. I always can't save the model successfully.
Here is my code.

`models.py`

```
class MyModel(models):
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    [...]
```

`forms.py`

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ['ip']
```

`views.py`

```
class MyView(FormView):
    form_class = MyForm
    [...]
```

I've tried to change the `psot()` method and manually added the `ip` field of `request.POST` but I just found that I didn't know how to pass the form instance..I spent all night to solve this problem and finally I failed ..
Tanks for helping in advance..

Thanks Daniel for answering this question.

I changed my code into this:

`views.py`

```
class PollView(FormView):
    template_name = 'poll.html'
    form_class = PollForm
    success_url = '/thanks/'

    def get_ip(self,request):
        if request.META.has_key('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'):  
            ip =  request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']  
        else:  
            ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        return ip

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.ip = self.get_ip(self.request)
        super(PollView,self).form_valid(form)
```

but I got an error:

```
ValueError at /
The view poll.views.PollView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Comment: This kind of thing should be done in `form_valid`: the docs give [an example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user) of accessing `request.user` there, but it's exactly the same principle.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I just stuck myself here.

Comment: I tried use `self.request` in `form_valid()` but this raises an error.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I added it in the question

Comment: You need to return the value of the super call.

Comment: Em.. thanks... I am really just a newbie ...

Answer (score 0):

You found the answer to your problem. And Daniel Roseman deserves some +1's

You can access the request object using the instance of the FormView class. Use

```
self.request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
```